# List doesn't load in django templates

Tags: python, django

So i'm trying to filter my model in this way in views.py:

```
news_list = list(models.Entry.objects.filter(category='news'))
```

and the problem is that the list cant be accessable from the django templates. 
this is the way I'm trying to access it in home.html:

```
{% for news in news_list %}

{{ news.title }}

{% endfor %}
```

and this:

```
{{ news_list.0.title }}
```

I'm sure the way that I created the list is right beauce when I loop through the list in the views.py it show up in the terminal.

I'm using python3.3 and django 1.8.3

views.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.views import generic
from . import models
from blog.models import Entry


class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.published()
    template_name = "home.html"
    paginate_by = 3
    news_list = Entry.objects.filter(category='news')
    i = 0
    for x in news_list:
        i = i+1
        print(x.title,i)
```

Comment: can you show the view?

Comment: The `filter` method you're using is returning a new `QuerySet`, an iterable similar to a list. So, there's no need for you to enclose the returned data inside another list.

Comment: @DejaVu I posted the view.py

Comment: @Nicksil I tried without the list() but still the same problem

Comment: I dont have experience with "generics", but it looks like you need to point out the model + return desired context like [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are trying to access `news_list` in the template when it is infact not present in the template.**

You need to pass `news_list` in the context data. Override the `get_context_data()` and pass this variable.

```
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.published()
    template_name = "home.html"
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['news_list'] = Entry.objects.filter(category='news') # pass 'news_list' in the context
        return context
```

Then in your template, you can use the normal `for` loop.

```
{% for news in news_list %}

    {{ news.title }}

{% endfor %}
```

**Note:** You don't need to convert the `QuerySet` to a list as it is already an `iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in django you don't access lists, but querysets. Try:

```
context['news_list'] = Entry.objects.filter(category='news')
```

Comment: I tried this before with models.Entry.objects.filter... but I still have the same problem., but when I just do Entry.objects.filter... I get:
name 'Entry' is not defined

Comment: I imported from blog.models import Entry, and now I don't have this problem, but still, nothing show up in the template

Comment: 1. I forgot to put new_list into context. 2. Maybe you have no Entry with category news? Try it in ./manage.py shell

Answer (score 0):

The queryset result can be used to iterate in django template. So there is no need to convert query set object into list. List is not iterable in django template though python does. You can use django-mptt is a premade solution, which should fit your problem quite good.

Comment: I have no knowledge of how to use django-mptt